# Docker / phpmyadmin: Unable to connecto

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I have the following docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  main:
    container_name: buspack_main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}
    command: bash -c "npm install --save && npm run start:dev"
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    restart: always

  db:
    container_name: buspack_db
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "backendnest"
    ports:
      - 23306:3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:rw

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: buspack_phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8030:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: buspack_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
networks:
  webnet:
volumes:
  db: {}
```

My problem Is that when I try to login with phpmyadmin I get the following error:

> mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

And also

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
    networks:
      - webnet
```

add webnet network to phpmyadmin service

Answer (score 0):

There are more options to solve the connection.

1. Add phpmyadmin container to `webnet` network as [Def Soudani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846758/3261501) suggests. The YML example provided overrides the  default network. Since the phpMyAdmin is lacking the network config, it won't be on the `webnet` docker network by default.
2. Remove all `networks` related config from the YML. Since compose already creates a default network ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)) for the containers within one YML file.
3. Use the `PMA_ARBITRARY=1` ([docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) )which allows you to enter a database server hostname on login form.

Example of my YML setup with custom bridge networking:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: myapp-mysql-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    volumes:
      - ./database/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - myapp-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      # 8080 is the host port and 80 is the docker port
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 20M
      MYSQL_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      # define your network where all containers are connected to each other
      - myapp-network

networks:
  myapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```